# Error when writing to 3rd case in HPS FPGA Avalon memory mapped interface

Tags: arm, vhdl, fpga, intel-fpga, soc

I need to get `count_x` 32 bit of data to HPS via avalon memory mapped interface. 1st and 2nd case were worked fine.And I got data to HPS. But in 3rd case `WHEN '2' => avs_s0_readdata <= count_x(31 downto 0);` it shows an error as **''2'' is not declared**, what does it mean? Vhdl was Done in Altera quartus 16.1 and HPS system was done in Qsys.

```
architecture behavior of encorder is
signal count : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
signal count_x : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
signal count_y : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0):= x"00000000";


begin   

    PROCESS(avs_s0_read)
    BEGIN
    IF avs_s0_read = '1' THEN
    CASE(avs_s0_address) IS


WHEN '2' => avs_s0_readdata <= count_x(31 downto 0);

WHEN others => avs_s0_readdata <= x"00000000";
END CASE;
ELSE
avs_s0_readdata <= x"00000000";

END IF;
END PROCESS;`
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can help the person who gives up time to help you. Your code is incomplete. We don't know what type `avs_s0_address` is (`'2'` is of type `character`. `avs_s0_address` will not be of that type). Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Without seeing a declarations for avs_s0_address it would appear that '2' is not an enumeration value of it's type.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your problem can't be duplicated (or more pointedly someone could contrive an example around your snippet that doesn't exhibit a syntax problem). If the type had been std_logic (base type std_ulogic) it's enumeration values would consist of character literals 'U', 'X', '0', '1', 'Z', 'W', 'L', 'H', and '-'.  Note the if condition didn't generate an error.

Comment: Another tool might give a more descriptive error message - `encorder.vhdl:34:6:error: can't match character literal '2' with type std_ulogic`. std_logic is a resolved subtype of std_ulogic - ('U', 'X', '0', '1', 'Z', 'W', 'L', 'H', and '-'). '2' is not a valid choice in a case statement, not representing a value of std_logic.

Comment: @user1155120 thanks I understood what you said, Then how can I get that 3rd 32 bits of data?.

Comment: You're code is still not an MCVE, but you can't select between 3 (or 4 items with '3') with a single binary bit representation. You'd expect more decoded selects (e.g. avs_s0_address) where each one would have a single useful state. Alternatively a composite value selecting one of more than two items.

Answer (score 1):

avs_s0_address is of type STD_LOGIC. This type does not include '2' as possible value, that's why it said it is not declared. STD_LOGIC is usually used to describe only two logic values of one bit, with is '0' and '1' You can find all options for example [here](https://www.cs.sfu.ca/~ggbaker/reference/std_logic/1164/std_logic.html)

Since I don't work with Avalon (I work with Xilinx FPGAs), I don't know exactly how it works, but your address bus seems to be one bit long. The type of this input should probably be std_logic_vector, so that you have more than one bit of address bus. Then, you can add signal of type integer:

```
signal avs_s0_address_int : integer;
```

and in architecture body, you can add line like this:

```
avs_s0_address_int <= to_integer(unsigned(avs_s0_address));
```

To have address value in integer type,  which is easier to compare in case statement.